# Docker compose run: How to access file on host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker compose service which can be run with a Web-UI (`docker compose up -d myservice`) or as one-time service (`docker compose run myservice`).

This service operates on csv-files which are either uploaded via Web-UI (this works) or specified as command line argument:

```
docker compose run -rm -e CSV_FILE=myfile.csv myservice
```

The directory of `myfile.csv` has to be mounted in `docker-compose.yml` first, e.g.

```
 myservice:
   [...]
   volumes:
     - ./mydir:/importpath:ro
```

How can I specify a directory with an absolute path of the host without mounting is in `docker-compose.yml` in advance?

Comment: A Docker container has an isolated filesystem, and without that `volumes:` mount it can't access host files at all.  If accessing host files is a key part of your process, would it make more sense to run it directly on the host, outside a container?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker cp`

From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SOURCE_PATH DEST_PATH
```